# Slick 3 multiple outer joins

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick

from Slick documentation, it's clear how to make a single left join between two tables.

```
val q = for {
  (t, v) <- titles joinLeft volumes on (_.uid === _.titleUid)
} yield (t, v)
```

Query q will, as expected, have attributes: `_1` of type `Titles` and `_2` of type `Rep[Option[Volumes]]` to cover for non-existing volumes.

Further cascading is problematic:

```
val q = for {
  ((t, v), c) <- titles 
                     joinLeft volumes on (_.uid === _.titleUid)
                     joinLeft chapters on (_._2.uid === _.volumeUid)
} yield /* etc. */
```

This won't work because `_._2.uid === _.volumeUid` is invalid given `_.uid` being not existing.

According to various sources on the net, this shouldn't be an issue, but then again, sources tend to target different slick versions and 3.0 is still rather new. Does anyone have some clue on the issue?
To clarify, idea is to use two left joins to extract data from 3 cascading 1:n:n tables.
Equivalent SQL would be:

```
Select *
from titles
left join volumes
    on titles.uid = volumes.title_uid
left join chapters
    on volumes.uid = chapters.volume_uid
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [multiple joins with slick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537925/multiple-joins-with-slick)

Comment: that answer is for Slick 2

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your second left join is no longer operating on a `TableQuery[Titles]`, but instead on what is effectively a `Query[(Titles, Option[Volumes])]` (ignoring the result and collection type parameters). When you join the resulting query on your `TableQuery[Chapters]` you can access the second entry in the tuple using the `_2` field  (since it's an `Option` you'll need to `map` to access the `uid` field):

```
val q = for {
  ((t, v), c) <- titles 
                     joinLeft volumes on (_.uid === _.titleUid)
                     joinLeft chapters on (_._2.map(_.uid) === _.volumeUid)
} yield /* etc. */
```

#### Avoiding `TupleN`

If the `_N` field syntax is unclear, you can also use [Slick's capacity for user-defined record types](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html#monomorphic-case-classes) to map your rows alternatively:

```
// The `Table` variant of the joined row representation
case class TitlesAndVolumesRow(title: Titles, volumes: Volumes)

// The DTO variant of the joined row representation
case class TitleAndVolumeRow(title: Title, volumes: Volume)

implicit object TitleAndVolumeShape
  extends CaseClassShape(TitlesAndVolumesRow.tupled, TitleAndVolumeRow.tupled)
```

Comment: Hi Sean - I corrected my code in question and added _2.uid. That is actually the problem given that in expression:
joinLeft chapters on (_._2.uid === _.volumeUid)
_._2 is not of a type Volumes, but it is of a type Rep[Option[Volumes]]. Therefore _._2.uid is not available and that is the source of issue.

Comment: @Bruno - updated with what I *believe* is the correct syntax for 3.0

Comment: I marked the answer as correct given that it does compile. However, I couldn't test it completely unfortunately because of other issues in slick I'm currently facing. Thanks!

Comment: It compiles if you put all those `joinLeft`s in one line. At least for me.