# Join three tables in Scala Slick or flatten nested tuples

Tags: scala, tuples, slick

I need to do INNER JOIN three tables because of foreign key in the first one as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "product" (
    "id" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "price" FLOAT NOT NULL,
    "categoryid" INT NOT NULL,
    "supplierid" INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(categoryid) references category(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(supplierid) references supplier(id)
);
```

In models I have method to handle list all:

```
def list(): Future[Seq[(Product, Category, Supplier)]] = db.run {
    productTable.join(categoryTable).on(_.categoryid === _.id).join(supplierTable).on(_._1.supplierid === _.id).result
  }
```

But this returns nested tuple instead of flat one: ((Product, Category), Supplier).
Then how should I join those tables to get flat tuple or, if not possible to do that, how can I flatten this tuple?

EDIT:

Actually the only solution I found which works for me is manual use of map:

```
  def list(): Future[Seq[(Product, Category, Supplier)]] = db.run {
   productTable.join(categoryTable).on(_.categoryid === _.id).join(supplierTable).on(_._1.supplierid === _.id).result.map(a => Seq((a(1)._1._1,a(1)._1._2,a(1)._2)))
  }
```

Which looks and feels horrible. But only this works so far ...
Any better ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiple joins with slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537925/multiple-joins-with-slick)

Comment: @AlleXyS: the answer you have provided gives result of nested tuples as I get now

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins are expressed as for comprehensions in Slick:

```scala
def list(): Future[Seq[(Product, Category, Supplier)]] = db.run {
  for {
    product <- productTable
    category <- categoryTable if product.categoryid === category.id
    supplier <- supplierTable if product.supplierid === supplier.id
  } yield (product, category, supplier)
}
```

I would also recommend you to check out Slick's support for foreign key queries. That would make the query quite a bit simpler, it would probably look something like this:

```scala
def list(): Future[Seq[(Product, Category, Supplier)]] = db.run {
  for {
    product <- productTable
    category <- product.category
    supplier <- product.supplier
  } yield (product, category, supplier)
}
```